# Tags with WooCommerce and Custom Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm no php pro (probably not even the level of enthusiast) but I can usually get my head around some PHP. I'm working on a WordPress install that's running WooCommerce. This piece of code is plaguing me – I need to pull the tags for an individual post from the database, and if the system finds a tag that matches the rules I will define in the `if` statement, it will display a particular piece of HTML. I was attempting to use the `in_array` function to search for a particular value that I know (in this case "games") as part of the array produced from `wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, "product_tag" )`. When I print the results I can clearly see that "games" is a value in the array, but the function only outputs the result of the `else` statement.

I thought this code would do the trick, as it seems pretty simple, but alas, so far, I have had no success. Someone a little brighter when it comes to PHP and WP have some ideas?

```
<?php

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, "product_tag" );
print_r ( $terms );


if ( in_array( "games", $terms ) ) {
echo '<img src="http://www.myurl.com/images/image.png" alt="games" />'; 
} elseif ( in_array( "bulk" , $terms) ) {
echo 'Hello bulk buyer!';
} else {
echo 'Howdy!';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return an array of term names, override the default args of `wp_get_post_terms()` as follows:

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, "product_tag", array( "fields" => "names" ) );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Comment: Thanks! Knew it had to be something simple like that – really appreciate the help!